# Launcher activity intent flags

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

I want to set some intent flags on the launcher activity of my app depending on user defined settings. For example, if user chooses not to turn off backlight, I should set FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON for launcher activity. Is there any way to get current intent and change it's flags before main activity is started?

I have been using PowerManager and WakeLock, but this way is kind of deprecated now so I want to update the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to get current intent and change it's flags before main activity is started?

No, sorry.

That being said, just call [`setKeepScreenOn()` on some `View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29) in your activity, and you will accomplish the same thing.

> I have been using PowerManager and WakeLock, but this way is kind of deprecated now

`PowerManager` and `WakeLock` are not deprecated, but they require an extra permission and are a bit risky -- the user will be unhappy if you fail to `release()` the `WakeLock` due to a crash or something.

Comment: Wow, seems to be exactly what I want! Gonna test in right now. Thanks!